# Single Responsibility Principle in MVC controllers. Critique required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, attributes, single-responsibility-principle

In my MVC4 app, there are some actions that need to behave differently depending on whether you are logged in (FormsAuthentication in my case) or not.

For example, I have an AccountController that has a method "RenderAccountAndProfile". If logged out, the corresponding partial view displays a log in prompt and button. If a user is logged in, the user's profile links appear, alongside a log out button.

The approach I've taken thus far in projects is to simply have an if statement along the lines...

```
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
```

However, I've just created what I think is a reasonably elegant alternative to this approach.

I have created a new attribute called AnonymousUsersOnly, which is very simple:

```
public class AnonymousUsersOnlyAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return !controllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

My AccountController class is decorated with the Authorize attribute. This then enabled me to have the following code:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [AnonymousUsersOnly]
    [ActionName("RenderAccountAndProfile")]
    public ActionResult RenderAccountAndProfile_Anonymous()
    {
        // create a "logged out" view model
        return Content("**NOT LOGGED IN** - LOG IN HERE");
    }

    [ActionName("RenderAccountAndProfile")]
    public ActionResult RenderAccountAndProfile_Authorized()
    {
        // create a "logged in" view model
        return Content("**LOGGED IN** - LOG OUT");
    }
}
```

I quite like this approach because my action methods conform to the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Each method now only deals with either a logged in situation or a logged out situation. I don't need any "if" statements directing the traffic any more.

This ought to make Unit Testing easier too, since each method is now only concerned with one outcome, not two. We can write unit tests to test each outcome separately, calling different methods.

Clearly, I can't have two methods with the same signature so that's why I have to use the ActionName attribute.

I would appreciate your critique here. Do you think this is an elegant solution or not? What are the pros and cons to this approach? And what security implications/risks could there be with this?

Comment: Why not just use the Authorize attribute at the action level, so that access is checked by mvc when calling the action and automatically take you to the login controller?

Comment: That's not quite the same functionality I desire though. I don't want a redirection to occur. What I've created above is a filter to select which action method to call depending on whether or not the user is authenticated. And also, decorating the entire class with [Authorize] and punching holes in it using [AllowAnonymous] is a safer approach because you cannot forget to apply authorization to all public methods. Otherwise, a single mistake causes your entire app to be compromised.

Comment: The typical use case for this would be to decorate action methods that render partial views, rather than ViewResults, although it certainly wouldn't be limited to this. I personally plan to use this approach to display different content depending on whether or not the user is authorized.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have here is a strategy pattern problem.  And you've implemented a (non-standard) strategy pattern, with a pretty clever implementation.  I worry that it is too clever.  That cleverness makes what the code is doing a lot less obvious to the uninitiated.

Offhand, I'd favor not bothering.  I often write controllers as very thin adapters over domain objects/services.  Therefore, I'm willing to take a pragmatic approach to design perfection in the controller.  In deciding between slight design problems and obvious code, always choose obvious code.

If you have thicker controllers, or some other reason to be really concerned about this problem here, you might consider a more traditional strategy pattern, perhaps aided by an abstract factory that provides different strategy implementations based on authentication state.  This meets your design objectives, and will be more immediately familiar to other programmers (if they know design patterns).

All that being said, I don't think keeping your clever solution will hurt anything that much.  I'd be tempted to change the name; Deny seems like a weird verb there to me.  Perhaps `AnonymousUsersOnly`, that would be a little more communicative to future programmers.

Comment: I totally agree with you that the pragmatic approach is often better than anything clever. But is my solution really that clever? It's essentially 1 line of code. I personally think it's elegant, but clever, no. If we were worried that the uninitiated wouldn't be able to follow what was going on, then why would the whole MVC framework allow us to subclass filters in the first place? Filters are kind of essential learning I would have thought for any would-be MVC programmer. I really like your suggestion regarding naming convention by the way. I'm going to edit my original post to reflect that.

Comment: Following on from my previous comment (due to lack of characters left!) virtually every MVC book or training guide has a whole chapter dedicated to the creation of custom filters. And as long as the naming convention is there (e.g. RenderAccountAndProfile_Anonymous or RenderAccountAndProfile_Authorized) then it should be very easy to read what's going on at a glance, wouldn't it?

Comment: Sure.  I don't think it's a bad solution.  The risk is that future maintainers don't understand.  They might not understand if your names don't make sense for them (all the time my names make sense to me, and confuse others), or if your method naming convention is not followed, or if these methods get separated spatially in a file.  It might also be a problem if you have a case where there is only one or the other, not both.  Depending on your context, all those risks might be low (you have a co-located team of MVC ninjas, for example).  If you feel like those risks are low, go for it.

Comment: tallseth, thank you for your comments, which I've found very useful. For me, it just 'feels right'. I've spent a few hours re-working a controller using this approach and I'm really pleased with how the appropriate methods look and feel cleaner, now performing one single function. However, I have taken your comments seriously and there is a time and place for my approach, it's got to be in the right context.

Answer (score 0):

I much better choose to (pseudocode) :

```
PartialView UserProfile() { ... }

PartialView Login() { ... }
```

and in view :

```
if (User.IsAuthenticated) {
    @Html.Action("UserProfile")
} else {
    @Html.Action("Login")
}
```

which can also be a DisplayTemplate, helper, or whatever you like so you just end up using

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=> User)
```